# Answering Stdin With String

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried many different ways to get this code to work.

Anyone know how to get this to work?

```
import sys

y = 1

def test():
    print("Hello?")
    x = (sys.stdin.readline())
    if x == ("hello"):
        print("Ah your back")
    else:
        print("Huh?")

while y == 1:
        test()
```

Comment: why not use `input()`

Comment: So if i used input() would it just be x = input()

Comment: yeah : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19294328/2425215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import sys

y = 1

def test():
    print("Hello?")
    x = (sys.stdin.readline())
    if x == ("hello\n"):
        print("Ah your back")
    else:
        print("Huh?")

while y == 1:
    test()
```

You are missing an `\n` or the newline character which signifies the end of the line in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `input()`? When It's possibly the most simplest approach...

```
import sys

y = 1

def test():
    print("Hello?")
    x = input()
    if x == ("hello"):
        print("Ah your back")
    else:
        print("Huh?")

while y == 1:
        test()
```

Answer (score 1):

it reads the line with a `\n` in the end so the comparison fails. try something like:

```
import sys

y = 1

def test():
    print("Hello?")
    x = (sys.stdin.readline())
    if x[:-1] == ("hello"):
        print("Ah your back")
    else:
        print("Huh?")

while y == 1:
        test()
```

Answer (score 1):

Strip the newline.

```
import sys

def test():
    print("Hello?")
    x = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
    if x == "hello":
        print("Ah your back")
    else:
        print("Huh?")

while True:
        test()
```

Comment: I need the while to be there so it loops and asks again.

Comment: @Arpit: about the while loop. It will not cause a stack overflow; test() is just called in sequence after termination.

Comment: @Minigeek22 How will you terminate your program ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

y = 1
def test():
    print("Hello?")
    x = sys.stdin.readline()
    if x == "hello\n":  #either strip newline from x or compare it with "hello\n".
        print("Ah your back")
    else:
        print("Huh?") 
test()  #your while will cause stack overflow error because of infinite loop.
```

http://ideone.com/Csbpn9